# How to publish Jenkins build artefact into Bitbucket downloads

Tags: jenkins, download, bitbucket

My Jenkins job shall build PDF documentation built from sources stored on Bitbucket.

I would like to post new artefact (a PDF file) into Downloads section of related Bitbucket repository.

Quick search did not reveal any existing plugin, serving requested purpose, but I could overlook some.

I would think of using Bitbucket API or some command line tool allowing that (like bitbucketcli, but I am not sure, it supports uploading into downloads section).

I would appreciate any reference to an existing working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They've provided an API for that . Find it [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/downloads-resource-812221853.html#downloadsResource-POSTafile) .

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky ,if possible please accept this answer so that people who drop by here can find it easily .

Answer (score 1):

I guess this feature is still in progress.

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/3251/add-custom-file-uploads-to-rest-api-bb

Here's a workaround way to upload things to your bitbucket repository (haven't tested):

https://bitbucket.org/Swyter/bitbucket-curl-upload-to-repo-downloads

Comment: Thanks for insight and tips, it works (tried the bitbucket-curl-upload-to-repo-downloads). Apparently, Atlassian does not seem to hurry with implementing real API for it.